# syntaxe error or access violation

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4

When I try to execute `php symfony doctrine:insert-sql` , i get this error :

> syntaxe error or access violation : 1072 key column 'id' doesn't existe in table

here is my schema.yml

```
Contact:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: contact
  columns:

    id_contact:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    nom:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    fonction_organisme:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    categorie:
      type: string(300)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    region:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    province:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    adresse:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel1:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel2:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel3:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel4:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    email:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    fax:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    ville:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    journal:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    commentaire:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    fix:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    image:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    owner:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Evenement:
      local: id_contact
      foreign: id_contact_event
      type: many
    Users : 
      class :   User
      refClass : OperationContact
      foreignAlias : Contacts  
Courrier:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: courrier
  columns:
    num_serie:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    annee:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    num_c:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    exp:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    dest:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    state:
      type: string(10)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    objet:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    image_c:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    date_recep:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    date_env:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    owner_c:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    user_c:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    type_c:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations : 
    Users : 
      class : User
      refClass : OperationC
      foreignAlias : Courriers
Evenement:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: evenement
  columns:
    id_event:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    date:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    action:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    id_contact_event:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Contact:
      local: id_contact_event
      foreign: id_contact
      type: one
OperationC:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: operation_c
  columns:
    id_user:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    num_serie:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    operation_c:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    date_op_c:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations : 
      User : { onDelete : CASCADE }
      Courrier : { onDelete : CASCADE }
OperationContact:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: operation_contact
  columns:
    id_contact:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    id_user:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    operation:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    date_op:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations : 
      User : { onDelete : CASCADE }
      Courrier : { onDelete : CASCADE }
User:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: user
  columns:
    id_user:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    nom_user:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    adresse_user:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    tel_user:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    login:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    password:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
```

Comment: i see that you edited something , but i can't see what was edited :s

Comment: I just highlighted the code. You can see what changes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11685020/revisions).

Comment: :) ok thnks , now it's better

Comment: Please try to narrow down the problem. I've tried to use your schema in a symfony 1.4.18 project and the errors I got are different than what you posted. Are you sure that with the posted schema you get this **exact** error? Moreover it would be helpful to know what relations you want to achieve between your tables because in your `schema.yml` is somehow mixed up.

Comment: yes i'm sure , i get this error with that schema , the only difference is the space between columns and id_contact in Contact

Comment: I got the same error with your schema, but you should clean more your schema. Like: you define to much useless `primary: false`, `fixed: false`, etc .. And your problem seems to come from a relation with Courrier because you define 2 PK and give only one FK to the relation (I guess).

Comment: should i modify the relation in operationc like that :user : {onDelete:CASDCADE ,local: num_serie,annee } ????

Comment: sorry not in user but in courrier relation

Comment: please , i need to know  how can i add the second PK to the relation